# uwsgi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aide.wsgi'?

Tags: uwsgi

I am trying to setup uwsgi for my Django project. It runs fine with

```
manage.py runserver
```

but when i try:

```
uwsgi --ini /data1/code/aide/etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
```

it runs error

full log:

> thunder lock: enabled uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address
> /data/tesla/aide_deploy/uwsgi.sock fd 3 uwsgi socket 1 bound to TCP
> address :8081 fd 4 Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Apr 19 2021,
> 17:20:37)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] PEP 405 virtualenv
> detected: /data/tesla/aide_deploy/envs/aide Set PythonHome to
> /data/tesla/aide_deploy/envs/aide Python main interpreter initialized
> at 0xb2fb60 python threads support enabled your server socket listen
> backlog is limited to 100 connections your mercy for graceful
> operations on workers is 60 seconds mapped 2479921384 bytes (2421798
> KB) for 30000 cores
> *** Operational MODE: preforking+async *** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi' unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not
> found or import error)
> /data/tesla/aide_deploy/envs/aide/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py:11:
> CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by
> the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in
> cryptography. The next release of cryptography will remove support for
> Python 3.6.   from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
> $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
> ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'rest_framework', 'rest_framework.authtoken',
> 'rest_framework_mongoengine', 'crispy_forms', 'django_filters',
> 'aide', 'celery', 'django_celery_beat', 'drf_multiple_model',
> 'django_celery_results', 'django_extensions'] WSGI app 0
> (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0xb2fb60 pid: 17050
> (default app)
> *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17050) spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17055, cores:
> 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 17056, cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI
> worker 3 (pid: 17057, cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 17058,
> cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 17059, cores: 1000)
> *** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x48f2d0] *** spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 17060, cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 17061,
> cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 17062, cores: 1000) spawned
> uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 17063, cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid:
> 17064, cores: 1000) spawned uWSGI worker 11 (pid: 17065, cores: 1000)
> spawned uWSGI worker 12 (pid: 17066, cores: 1000)

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /data/tesla/aide_deploy/aide/apps 
wsgi-file       = django_base/wsgi.py
module          = aide.wsgi
home            = /data/tesla/aide_deploy/envs/aide
master          = true
workers         = 2
processes       = 30
max-requests    = 5000
socket          = /data/tesla/aide_deploy/uwsgi.sock
socket          = :8081
vacuum          = true
buffer-size     = 65535
daemonize       = /data1/log/aide/uwsgi/aide.log
pidfile         = /data/tesla/aide_deploy/uwsgi.pid
enable-threads  = true
harakiri        = 600
gevent          = 1000
post-buffering  = 1
thunder-lock    = true
uwsgi_read_timeout = 600
```

can someone tell me how i solve the error